# How can I force ALSA to recognize my sound card as a different model?

Tags: drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, alsamixer

I have a Lenovo Legion 7i laptop, and the sound does not work in Linux at all, but does work in Windows. Alsamixer identifies the laptop as having an ALC287, but several websites indicate that the card is actually an ALC3306.

How can I force ALSA to use the ALC3306 driver? I'm hoping that makes my sound work.

If anyone is wondering, it's not just me having this problem, as there are multiple users with the same issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555

Comment: Is there a driver for the ALC3306 in the first place? I have an old kernel, so I can't have a look, but if you got the source for the newest kernel (which you'd need), have a look at `.../sound/pci/hda`, which contains "patches" for different codecs (the ALC... is a codec). That is assuming you have Intel HDA hardware (have a look at `dmesg` to confirm). It's quite possible there's no "patch" for the ALC3306 yet.

Comment: And neither of the core ALSA developers give a f**k about the issue. Linux at its best, as always. And the bug is almost three months old.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov : At the end of the day, it seems more being a codec than a driver. So... Alsa-devs once again (through some clumsy helper falling back) or once again Realtek shipping it's hardware with... proprietary firmwares not... 'yet' available under Linux ?

Comment: The HDA codec doesn't need any firmware - it's all down to either being supported or not. Looks like ALSA developers are busy doing something else rather than supporting new HW.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov : The **generic** HD-Audio codecs do not need any firmware. Only the **generic**.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. There's no firmware for the HDA driver in the Linux kernel source or firmware trees.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. it looks like my initial assumption was wrong - the laptop might not use the ALC3306 (there is another variant that does). The core problem still remains, so I guess I'll ask a new question.

Comment: Superseded by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611530/how-can-i-get-my-unsupported-sound-card-to-work-with-alsa

Comment: @BluFeniX what's your Legion 7i model version? According to the PSREF from Lenovo website, the Legion 15IMHg05 shall have ALC3306