# How can I get my unsupported sound card to work with ALSA?

Tags: drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, alsamixer

I get no sound via the speakers of my Lenovo Legion 7i laptop, which alsamixer tells me is using a **Realtek ALC287**.

I have tried various Linux distros and kernel combinations, including Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04, with both the default and mainline kernels (5.7.x & 5.8.x), and Manjaro with 5.6.x, 5.7.x and 5.8.x kernels.

In each case, I made sure to disable Auto-Mute in alsamixer, and turn all volume levels to maximum. In all cases, I get no sounds from the speakers (running speaker-test, playing music, etc.). I *am* able to get sound via headphones and HDMI (though I believe HDMI is via a different sound card).

Also, I can see that there is some kind of sound activity occurring when I look at pavucontrol (the reddish-orange bar that indicates a sound is playing), but there is no actual sound produced from the speakers.

My alsa-info.sh results (from Manjaro on 5.6.15) are here (ignore this, newer one below):

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=ba86fe76a9d9cf1cced56600edf82eb206a36a72

I am happy to run the script again (or any other tool) from a different distro/kernel combination, please just let me know what would be helpful.

I have already filed a [bug report with that same information](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555), but sadly the only responses have been from other people with the same issue.

**What can I do to get my sound working?** I am experienced with software development, but not drivers or kernel space. Willing to learn and try anything at this point.

**UPDATE**

alsa-info.sh using a more recent kernel:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4272343a3590cc08f192f98113dedfc0418afe52

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The info you provided has a section about the codec, and that tells you that this particular codec is not recognized:

```
Codec: Realtek Generic
...
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0287
Subsystem Id: 0x17aa3813
Revision Id: 0x100002
```

On my system, the first line says

```
Codec: Realtek ALC892
```

The code for the patches that deal with the various codecs is in `/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c`, at least for the relatively old kernel I use at the moment.

So to get your sound working, you need to debug what's going wrong with the codec, then write a patch, and include it in the code, so everyone else with that hardware can have it working.

The codec information can be dumped with `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`. Read up on how an Intel HDA Codec works, and debug it.

I recommend disabling Pulseaudio. `hda-verb` from the `alsa-tools` package (at least that's how it is called on Debian) may also help.

You can google datasheets for older codecs to understand how they work.

Comment: The latest driver already has an entry for `0x10ec0287`. But nobody knows how the chip is wired up on that particular machine.

Comment: Which means the OP needs to at least uprgrade to the latest kernel, and try again.

Comment: Whoops. I copied my bug report verbatim, and forgot that I had already run alsa-info.sh with a more recent kernel. Although not the newest, it does recognize the codec. http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4272343a3590cc08f192f98113dedfc0418afe52

Comment: So the next step is debugging:  I recommend to disable Pulseaudio, use `aplay` to play a WAV file, look at the codec and see if you can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX any progress?